# Live data cell split and add

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I am using live data sheet in which I want to split each cell number into individual number and add them.

```
Example: 
cell A1 contains number 265.96
Into 26596 and add these number
ie 2+6+5+9+6
```

Comment: UDF : You could for example walk the length of the cell value summing if isnumeric.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a formula like so in B1:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")))),1))
```

Confirm with: `CTLR+SHIFT+ENTER`

[image]

Comment: @Umesh, for real? On my machine this works like a treat. Whether values are text or numeric....

Answer (score 0):

An UDF might look like

```
Public Function GetSum(ByRef rng As Range) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(rng.Value)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(rng.Value, i, 1)) Then GetSum = GetSum + Mid(rng.Value, i, 1)
    Next i
End Function
```